# Using GWT Editor Framework, how to highlight invalid fields?

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

Using GWT Editor Framework, how can I highlight invalid fields (for example, change the corresponding labels' colors to red)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to implement [`HasEditorErrors`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/HasEditorErrors.html). Even though the [`ValueBoxEditorDecorator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/ValueBoxEditorDecorator.html) is [not ready for prime time](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5465), it's still a good example of how this works.